# How to address file conflicts when performing squash merges between develop and master

Tags: git, azure-devops

At the company I work for, we've been attempting to use a Git workflow that uses the following branches:

1. Master - Contains commits that represent releases
2. Release Candidate (RC) - Temporary branch based on develop to permit testing before release
3. Develop - Contains full history of application development
4. Feature branches - Created for the development of single features before merging back into develop

For a visual guide, this is somewhat similar to the following (with the exceptions being that the RC branch is not shown, and that feature branches are squash merged before being pulled into develop):

[image]

Image source: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

For the most part this works well. However, the approach is hitting a roadblock between the RC and master branches, which seems to be related to the use of squash merges.

We have no issues performing squash merges between feature branches and develop, but for some unknown reason when we perform squash merges between the RC branch and master we are receiving file merge conflicts, indicating that the same files have been "edited in both". This warning is not being shown when performing the squash merge between the feature branches and develop, or at least not as far as I can remember. Any squash merges from a feature branch to develop respect that the latest changes take precedence, whereas the RC to master squash merge seems to ignore the fact that the same files have been added previously.

For reference, we are performing the squash merges using Azure DevOps, during the completion of pull requests. The error message that is shown is as follows:

[image]

Image source: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.conflicts-tab#overview

Other points to note:

1. There is a shared ancestor between master and the RC/develop branches, which is the initial commit.
2. This file merge conflict seems to be based on not correctly handling files that it's already imported. For example, between two of our releases we had 80+ file conflicts, with warnings that the files needed to be added, despite files of the same name and path already existing in the master branch.

What I'd really like to know is, is there an issue with the approach being taken, or are there issues with the tools (Git or Azure DevOps)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you want to do squash merges? why would you squash a hotfix into another patch?

Comment: The idea behind the release candidate branch is to provide a stable version to test against. Any hotfixes would be applied to develop first. The idea behind using squash merging the release candidate into master is to tidy up the contents of master so that it only contains releases (+ the original commit). As you can see from the Atlassian link, this isn't a new approach, it's clearly being done by others. Have you got any insights into why the issue being described is occurring?

Comment: How did you resolve this? We are currently facing the same issue...

Comment: Vetterjack, we now don't bother using a separate master branch, we just push to develop and tag the commits in develop to denote important milestones. Not the workflow I was hoping to achieve but it works fine.